# How to calculate growth rates per day in R

Tags: r

I'm still a newbie at `R` and have the following data frame with mussel data I measured in the field. I want to get a growth rate per day for each `locID` (I have `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, `B4`, `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, `C4`, `D1`, `D2`, `D3` and `D4` so a loop of a function would be ideally but I only included `C1` for now) separately for 10 mm mussels and for 15 mm mussels and for each depth. So getting the growth rate per day from first sample would be subtracting length `11,08` (`08-08-2017    39  1   C1  0,5 10  blue`) from `9,92` (`03-07-2017 3   1   C1  0,5 10  blue`) and dividing it by days `39` (`08-08-2017    39  1   C1  0,5 10  blue        11,08`) - `3` (`03-07-2017  3   1   C1  0,5 10  blue        9,92`)
Can anybody give me any tips on how to try to find a way to calculate this in `R`? I know I'm asking a lot, I'm hoping somebody is willing to take the time to help!

Thank you in advance!

```
date    n=  session locID   depth   org_length  replica     length
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  0,5 10  blue        9,92    
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  2,5 10  blue        10,33   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  4,5 10  blue        9,78    
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  6,5 10  blue        10,45   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  0,5 10  green       9,89    
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  2,5 10  green       10,32   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  4,5 10  green       9,86    
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  6,5 10  green       10,28   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  0,5 10  purple      10,36   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  4,5 10  purple      10,35   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  6,5 10  purple      10,47   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  0,5 10  red     10,48   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  2,5 10  red     9,64    
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  4,5 10  red     10,08   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  6,5 10  red     10,37   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  0,5 15  blue        15,51   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  2,5 15  blue        14,84   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  4,5 15  blue        15,53   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  6,5 15  blue        14,54   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  0,5 15  green       14,89   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  2,5 15  green       15,29   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  4,5 15  green       14,97   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  6,5 15  green       14,77   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  0,5 15  purple      15,04   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  4,5 15  purple      15,17   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  6,5 15  purple      15,33   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  0,5 15  red     14,86   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  2,5 15  red     15,27   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  4,5 15  red     14,55   
03-07-2017  3   1   C1  6,5 15  red     15,12   
13-07-2017  13  1   C1  2,5 10  purple      10,52   
13-07-2017  13  1   C1  2,5 15  purple      15,62   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  0,5 10  blue        11,08   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  2,5 10  blue        12,95   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  4,5 10  blue        10,67   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  6,5 10  blue        10,38   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  0,5 10  green       10,91   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  2,5 10  green       12,56   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  4,5 10  green       10,81   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  6,5 10  green       10,69   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  0,5 10  purple      11,25   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  2,5 10  purple      10,83   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  4,5 10  purple      10,37   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  6,5 10  purple      10,5    
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  0,5 10  red     10,45   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  2,5 10  red     11,39   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  4,5 10  red     12,02   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  6,5 10  red     10,32   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  0,5 15  blue        15,95   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  2,5 15  blue        15,75   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  4,5 15  blue        15,48   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  6,5 15  blue        14,8    
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  0,5 15  green       16,37   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  2,5 15  green       16,66   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  4,5 15  green       15,37   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  6,5 15  green       14,67   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  0,5 15  purple      14,96   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  2,5 15  purple      15,49   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  4,5 15  purple      15,15   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  6,5 15  purple      15,67   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  0,5 15  red     16,21   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  2,5 15  red     15,19   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  4,5 15  red     15,14   
08-08-2017  39  1   C1  6,5 15  red     15,54   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  0,5 15  blue        15,94   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  2,5 15  blue        15,68   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  4,5 15  blue        15,48   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  6,5 15  blue        14,5    
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  0,5 15  green       16,33   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  2,5 15  green       16,7    
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  4,5 15  green       15,33   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  6,5 15  green       14,62   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  0,5 15  purple      14,96   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  2,5 15  purple      15,58   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  4,5 15  purple      15,17   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  6,5 15  purple      15,64   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  0,5 15  red     16,17   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  2,5 15  red     15,17   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  4,5 15  red     15,1    
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  6,5 15  red     15,57   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  0,5 10  blue        11,08   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  2,5 10  blue        12,95   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  4,5 10  blue        11,15   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  6,5 10  blue        10,47   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  0,5 10  green       10,91   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  2,5 10  green       12,52   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  4,5 10  green       10,88   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  6,5 10  green       10,7    
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  0,5 10  purple      11,3    
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  2,5 10  purple      10,93   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  4,5 10  purple      10,35   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  6,5 10  purple      10,51   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  0,5 10  red     10,45   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  2,5 10  red     11,37   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  4,5 10  red     12,03   
05-09-2017  67  1   C1  6,5 10  red     10,2    
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  0,5 15  blue        15,95   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  2,5 15  blue        15,64   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  4,5 15  blue        15,47   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  6,5 15  blue        14,55   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  0,5 15  green       16,37   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  2,5 15  green       16,72   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  4,5 15  green       15,33   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  6,5 15  green       14,61   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  0,5 15  purple      14,81   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  2,5 15  purple      15,54   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  4,5 15  purple      15,3    
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  6,5 15  purple      15,65   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  0,5 15  red     16,19   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  2,5 15  red     15,14   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  4,5 15  red     15,07   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  6,5 15  red     15,51   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  0,5 10  blue        11,2    
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  2,5 10  blue        12,92   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  4,5 10  blue        11,51   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  6,5 10  blue        10,43   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  0,5 10  green       10,89   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  2,5 10  green       12,5    
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  4,5 10  green       10,67   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  6,5 10  green       10,85   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  0,5 10  purple      11,28   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  2,5 10  purple      11,14   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  4,5 10  purple      10,95   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  6,5 10  purple      10,61   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  0,5 10  red     10,44   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  2,5 10  red     11,96   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  4,5 10  red     12,67   
29-09-2017  91  1   C1  6,5 10  red     10,18
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
# sort the data (important)
df <- df[order(df$locID, df$depth, df$org_length, df$replica, df$n.), ]

# calculate rates
rates <- by(df, list(df$locID, df$depth, df$org_length, df$replica), function(x) {
  c(NA, diff(x$length)/diff(x$n.))})
rate_overall <- by(df, list(df$locID, df$depth, df$org_length, df$replica), function(x) {
  rep(diff(x$length[c(1, length(x$length))])/diff(x$n.[c(1, length(x$n.))]), nrow(x))})

# add rates to data
df$growth_rate <- unlist(rates)
df$overall_growth_rate <- unlist(rate_overall)
```

You get

```
> head(df)
          date n. session locID depth org_length replica length growth_rate overall_growth_rate
1   03-07-2017  3       1    C1   0.5         10    blue   9.92         NA        0.0145454545
33  08-08-2017 39       1    C1   0.5         10    blue  11.08 0.03222222        0.0145454545
81  05-09-2017 67       1    C1   0.5         10    blue  11.08 0.00000000        0.0145454545
113 29-09-2017 91       1    C1   0.5         10    blue  11.20 0.00500000        0.0145454545
5   03-07-2017  3       1    C1   0.5         10   green   9.89         NA        0.0294318182
37  08-08-2017 39       1    C1   0.5         10   green  10.91 0.07277778        0.0294318182
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply!

I indeed want to split the data for locID, depth, org_length and replica. The only thing is that I have multiple measuring days per sample so a formula dividing the difference won't work I think. It might work if I only use the length measured at the beginning and the length measured at the end.  Also, when I type in your code I get the following error:

Error in df$locID : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Do you know why that is? Thank you in advance and I look forward to hearing from you!

Comment: regarding your error, the code assumes your data is stored in an object called `df`, so either do that, or substitute `df` for whatever the name of your data set is.

The function calculates the rate based on any 2 consecutive measuring events, *e.g.,* between `03-07-2017`, and `08-08-2017`, `08-08-2017` and `05-09-2017`, and between `05-09-2017` and `29-09-2017`.
If that is not what you want, please clarify.

While I'm at it, I will edit the code to make it simpler and faster..

Comment: Thank you again for you quick response! Calculations based on consecutive measuring events is exactly what I wanted, great! The data stored in my df is written as 2017-07-03 instead of 03-07-2017, does that make any difference?

Comment: One last question: I need one more column with the sum of the individually calculated growth rates per sample (so eg blue, 10mm, 0,5 depth), can you help me?

Comment: You can do something like: `df$sums <- unlist(lapply(rates, function(x) rep(sum(x, na.rm = T), length(x))))`. However, be aware that the sum of the individual rates is **not** equivalent to the growth rate between *e.g.,* days 3 and 91 (for `C1 0.5 10 blue`, `diff(c(9.92, 11.2))/diff(c(3, 91))` = 0.01454545 but `sum(df$rates[1:4], na.rm = T)` = 0.0372222222).

Comment: Yes thank you again! I understand you comment as well. I don't think my question was clear before I aplogize but I need a sum of the rates per value divided by the amount of rates, so divided by 3 for each sample. Do you know how I could adjust this? After that I was go on working on it myself! :)

Comment: Just edit the function provided to `lapply` in my previous comment to calculate `sum(...)/3`. Without wanting to veer off topic, wouldn't it be better to just calculate the rate based on the first and last measurement and divided by the total number of days, though? I am not sure if `sum(rates)/3` is a useful index...

Comment: Dear Milan, thank you for your response. Calculating the rate based on the first and last measurment would also certainly be possible. I am calculating periodical growth rates now in order to compare them with cyanobacteria concentration data I also obtained. Would there be an easy way to calculate the growth rate based on the first and last measurment day using your previous codes?

Comment: No worries! For the overall rate code, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help Milan, you're a lifesaver!